# How do I get reputation to up vote something on stack overflow?

Tags: discussion

I see lots of great work on stack overflow and would like to upvote the responses that have helped me, but it appears I can't, because I need to have at least 15 reputation points. So, how can I get those reputation points to upvote other votes ? Am I suppose to go trolling answering other posts, hoping someone with reputation will upvote it ?

Comment: "Am I suppose to go trolling answering other posts, hoping someone with reputation will upvote it?"  -- yep.

Comment: as you said yourself, you upvote the responsed that helped you... so you get reputation by being helpful

Comment: To note - there's little point in answering questions that have already been answered unless you bring something *new* to the table, improving already given information.

Answer (score 1):

taken from stackoverflow's FAQ:

> The primary way to gain reputation is by posting good questions and
>   useful answers. Your peers will vote on your posts, and those votes
>   will cause you to gain (or, in rare cases, lose) reputation:
>
> answer is voted up
>   +10    question is voted up
>   +5     answer is accepted
>   +15    (+2 to acceptor) question is voted down
>   -2     answer is voted down
>   -2     (-1 to voter)

[Stackoveflow FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation)